# Which software and hardware allows BIOS control from Operating System?

Tags: bios, operating-systems

Which software and hardware allows BIOS control from Operating System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the operating system is windows asus makes a tool and has supported boards listed here: http://support.asus.com/technicaldocuments/technicaldocuments_content.aspx?no=714

Comment: Ok. Thanks!
But I want also to configurate the BIOS and not only update it

Comment: Short of a linux bios I am not of aware of a way to do this...complicated to get installed and limited hardware support.